# Mac Safari/Chrome/Opera Native White Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, webkit, scrollbar

I notice that when an website have dark backgrounds aplied to `html` or `body` tag, all Mac webkit browsers(Safari/Chrome/Opera), natively changes scrollbar's theme to a white one. BUT, it's not happen on any other element's scrollbar.

[image]

Is there's any way to set div's scrollbars to have the native white theme *without* using `::webkit-scrollbar` CSS property?

Maybe a JavaScript to hack browser's behavior or something to set it on this unique div.

Again: I don't want to customize it with `::webkit-scrollbar` CSS property. The motive is that it loses its native behavior of hover, fade an timeout which is not fully customizable by native browsers CSSproperties.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:** use a jQuery plugin, such as [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com), [JQuery Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) , or [Perfect Scrollbar](http://yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar). They would allow you to style a scrollbar for a selected element any way you want, including animated behaviors.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. It breaks all the page layout and didn't change the native scrollbar.

Comment: How about a crazy approach of having two `<body>` tags in one HTML document?

Comment: I'm not trying to use 2 bodies, just trying to make the scrollbar of other elements change it's theme on dark backgrounds as well.

Comment: Nah, If I have to use custom plugins it's easier to just customize it via CSS, and that's what I don't want. I'll keep searching a way to switch by the native white scrollbar. Tks anyway.

Comment: Did you try absolute positioning of the element?

Comment: I tried now that you told me this, but didn't work too, nor with absolute, static, relative and fixed.

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert, but I believe it could access browser's behavior and set it to a specific element.

Comment: A browser can only partially be controlled by JavaScript. Since you mentioned that you were looking for a solution better than CSS, one of the jQuery plugins mentioned above should do the trick. You will be able to set fade in and timeout any way you want. Additional advantage: it would also be cross-browser (including FF and IE). Answer updated.

Comment: Well, I'm already using a lightweight scroll plugin to simulate mac srollbars on Windows browsers(even I didn't reach a good result with it). I ask here because I want to find a way to trigger the native mac one. But if it's impossible for now, I'll accept your answer as right and move on. Thanks for your attention and patience, keep going.